# Uniformization Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry

I understand this statement of Uniformization Theorem:

Every simply connected Riemann surface is conformally
equivalent to the unit disk, the complex plane, or the Rieman $n$ sphere.

However, the following statement totally throws me out:

Every connected 2-manifold is diffeomorphic to a quotient of one of the three constant curvature model surfaces listed above by a discrete group of isometries acting freely
and properly discontinuously. Therefore, every connected 2-manifold has a
complete Riemannian metric with constant Gaussian curvature.

From the context, "the three constant curvature model surfaces listed above" are zero curvature, $1/R^2$ and $-1/R^2$.

Could anyone explain how these two are equivalent? I am particularly lost at the terms *"a quotient of"* and *"a discrete group of isometries acting freely
and properly discontinuously"*.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to read [Wikipedia's page on group actions](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Group_action&oldid=553862684). In particular sections 1 through 4 and 7.