# Application of Uniformization Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry

The statement is, if a compact, connected, orientable surface
has nonpositive Gaussian curvature, the Gauss–Bonnet theorem forces its
genus to be at least 1, and then the uniformization theorem tells us that
its universal covering space is topologically equivalent to the plane.

I am confused with the last statement here - how can we draw the conclusion from [Uniformization Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421538/uniformization-theorem) that its universal covering space is topologically equivalent to the plane?

Answer (score 1):

The torus is the quotient of the flat plane, same as a square with opposite edges identified, the higher genus (multi-hole) tori are quotients of the hyperbolic plane (Poincare Disc) by [Fuchsian groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_polygon), quotients other polygons with geodesic arcs as edges.

Comment: Thanks Will. I guess my questions is then what is quotient? Is it equivalent to gluing operation..? Thank you. :-)

Comment: @MathSnail, the Fuchsian model goes together with the "metric" fundamental polygon, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface#Hyperbolic_Riemann_surfaces  while the gluing operation with polygons where all the vertices are equivalent is the "standard" polygon. So I suppose they are not quite the same. Read the various Wikipedia parts, especially http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_polygon#Fundamental_polygon_of_a_compact_Riemann_surface

Comment: Certainly worth getting one-hole and two-hole tori, as rubber dog toys I guess, and see if you can draw the "standard" and "metric" fundamental polygons on them. I'm curious now, I think I will do that myself. There is a big pet supply store near me.